How to refresh SessionFactory or SpringContext programmatically with SpringBoot and Hibernate via API for some tests
I run a lot of black box test with cypress against my running spring Boot application.
Most of the tests don't care about the state of the database (as black box testing might suggest). But a few tests need a clean database.
So I wrote myself a little API:
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Validated
@Profile({ Profil.DEVELOPMENT, Profil.INTEGRATION} )
public class CleanDatabaseController {

    private final Flyway flyway;
    private final Environment environment;
    private final CacheService cacheService;

     @MutationMapping
        public void cleanDatabase() {
            if (environment.matchesProfiles(Profil.PRODUCTION)) {
                return;
            }
            flyway.clean();
            flyway.migrate();
            cacheService.evictCaches();
        }
    }

To achive this I added this line to application-development.properties
spring.flyway.clean-disabled=false

The cypress test can then call this mutation before running the test
cy.graphql("mutation { cleanDatabase }");

Everything worked fine so far. But when a test saves any entity with hibernate the generated ID value is negative.
Our @Entity IDs are mapped like this:
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private int id = 0;

And our sequences are created like this:
CREATE SEQUENCE customer_seq
     START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 50;

I guess hibernate has still some context cached about the Sequence generator and just fails because of this. Similar if you haven't configured your sequence generator properly
Do I need to reset my hibernate EntityManagerFactory/SessionFactory?
Or should I refresh the complete Spring Context?
If yes, how can I do this?

Meanwhile I found this solution to reset the sequences:
  private void resetSequenceGenerators() throws IllegalAccessException {
        MappingMetamodelImpl metamodel = (MappingMetamodelImpl) entityManager.getMetamodel();
        for(EntityPersister entityPersister : metamodel.entityPersisters().values()) {
            if (entityPersister.hasIdentifierProperty()
                    && entityPersister.getGenerator() != null
                    && entityPersister.getGenerator() instanceof SequenceStyleGenerator sequenceStyleGenerator
                    && sequenceStyleGenerator.getOptimizer() instanceof PooledOptimizer pooledOptimizer) {

                Field noTenantStateField = ReflectionUtils.findField(PooledOptimizer.class, "noTenantState");
                assert noTenantStateField != null;
                noTenantStateField.setAccessible(true);
                noTenantStateField.set(pooledOptimizer, null);
            }
        }
    }

